# Is Facebook using oauth2 for its FB native iOS app?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

I know that Facebook provides an oauth2 access for his API.

My question is more focused to know if Facebook native iOS app is using oauth2 or digest/basic/other authentication over https ?

Because Facebook is the "owner" of the framework, it is not very adapted to oauth (more adapted to execute requests/login on behalf of someone).

Can someone clarify my point ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're really interested - install it on simulator, log in with an account and trace all these actions on host machine with something like Wireshark.